# New component in Navbar, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I'm working on a site where users can draw on an empty canvas (`doodle component`).  I want to create a sidebar that will have a '+' link that a user can click on to create a new `doodle component` or folder that will house multiple components.  Ultimately, I would like a user to have folders and and subfolders of their doodles.  I would like the file structure to mimic that of the screenshot below.  What would be the best way of going about this.  I am considering using react router to accomplish this but was wondering if there are alternatives out there that I may be missing?  Any suggestions will be appreciated.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you want the user to go back and forth between doodles, you could use router. Otherwise you could just use the component's state to clean the current doodle and start with a new one. A bit more info would be great to get a better idea.

Comment: `react-router` is probably a good tool for that job, yes. Your question is rather broad and not a good fit for StackOverflow, so I've voted to close it. Perhaps try again when you run into more specific problems.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickHund react router with some wild card is the best approach for this case. Also if you run into more issues, perhaps post some code snippet or create a live demo.